# compass (grunt-contrib-compass) sprites paths problems

Tags: gruntjs

Im using the **grunt-contrib-compass** pluckin, and I just cant get it to behave the way i want, the problem is that the image path in my css file are wrong.

Have been playing around with the [parameters](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-compass) but i cant figure it out (sadface)

**My folders:**

```
/root
   /assets
       /css
       /images
           /sprites <-- generated images
```

**And the configuration in my gruntfile.js**

```
compass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                 sassDir: 'src/scss'
                ,cssDir: 'assets/css'
                ,raw: 'preferred_syntax = :sass\n' 

                ,imagesDir:             "assets/images/"
                //,imagesPath:          "assets/images/sprites/"
                ,generatedImagesDir:    "assets/images/sprites/"
                ,generatedImagesPath:   "assets/images/sprites/"

            }
        }
    }
```

**The image url in my css file:**

```
/assets/images/sprites/interface-s04f47928b4.png
```

**But it should really be:**

```
../images/sprites/interface-s04f47928b4.png
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so i figured it out (finaly)

```
,imagesDir:             "assets/images/"
,generatedImagesDir:    "assets/images/sprites/"
,generatedImagesPath:   "assets/images/sprites/"
,httpGeneratedImagesPath: "../images/sprites"
```

Comment: Your answer was very helpful! I needed an input (imagesDir) and an output (generatedImagesDir) for my sprites and this the way to do it. BTW the generatedImagesPath wasn't necessary for me.

Comment: Thanks for that, been struggling with it for so long!